# one wallet address, multiple users, what is the best way to keep the private key secured?

Tags: wallets, security, myetherwallet, private-key, keymanagement

I would like to develop an application using the web3j. However, it needs to be just one wallet that multiple users will deposit and withdraw from. The allowances are kept in a centralized database. My concern is safety of this approach, since the private key must be kept safe and used only by the wallet application.

I am thinking about creating a separate micro-service and put the read-only restriction to an encrypted file containing the key, while allowing only a certain application to communicate with the wallet.

What do you think would be the best approach ?
Please note that I must use the single wallet and a single secret-key.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, I would research [multi-sing](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Multi-signature) wallets. (Wallets that require a multitude of private keys). Therefore if one is stolen, it is still not possible to access the wallet on your own.

Using a single private key in such a case is simply asking for trouble. A single point of failure is never a good thing in a design.